# PouchDB about 3x slower inserting 4800 documents over websql

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Been exploring the use of pouch db so we could potentially leverage its offline sync instead of doing our own. We have a cordova app that pulls data from a REST API and saves it into a web sql store. Part of this is around 5k physical locations for various stores. I timed it on the cordova app, and we download the stores & save them, along with another request for project information in about 11 seconds. Just the saving of these 5k records as documents in pouch db takes 30 seconds. Not counting request time.

Here's what i do:

```
let db = PouchProxy.getDB();
this.render("loading", { message: "Saving locations" });
// stores from api
let stores = res.stores;
let docs = [];
// check for saved stores, checking ids that start with store_
db.allDocs({ include_docs: true, startkey: 'store_', endkey: 'store_\uffff' }).then((results) => {
  // go through saved stores
  for (let row of results.rows) {
    let doc = row.doc;
    // get the number id. The _id is simply 'store_idnumfromapi'
    let id = parseFloat(doc._id.split('store_')[1]);
    if (isNaN(id)) {
      throw "Cannot be NaN";
    }
    // iterate through stores from api
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
      let store = stores[i];
      // find store and local record
      if (store.id === id) {
        // sets the _id and other properties from the store api object to a new object
        let map = PouchProxy.storeToDocMap(store);
        // set revision
        map._rev = doc._rev;
        docs.push(map);
        stores.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // go through remaining stores and push to docs set
  for (let store of stores) {
    docs.push(PouchProxy.storeToDocMap(store));
  }

  // save all the things
  console.log(Date.now());
  return db.bulkDocs(docs);
}).then(() => {
  // this the second time stamp i use to get the 30 seconds
  console.log(Date.now());
  // calculate geolocation stuff
  for (let store of docs) {
    store.distance = this.distanceBetweenPoints(store, { lat: position.coords.latitude, long: position.coords.longitude });
  }
  docs.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.distance - a.distance;
  });
  this.render("store-list", { stores: docs.slice(0, 19) });
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Hope the code is clear enough. I thought about switching to one document for the stores, but then i feel like individual lookups will be much more difficult and expensive.

**Edit, revised code. Performance actually worse :(**

As per suggestion, I broke down the list of 5000 into chunks. I played with a couple different sizes. 300 & 500, both had really similar times for saving the data. Here's how it looks now:

```
saveLocations(db, stores) { // position
  var storeSlices = [];
  stores.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
  });
  stores.eachSlice(300, (slice) => {
    storeSlices.push(slice);
  });

  console.log(Date.now());
  this.commitBatch(db, storeSlices, 0, () => {
    console.log(Date.now());
    // this.sortAndRenderStores(docs, position);
    this.render("store-list", { stores: [] });
  });
}

commitBatch(db, slices, index, callback) {
  let stores = slices[index];
  db.allDocs({ include_docs: true, startkey: 'store_' + stores[0].id, endkey: 'store_' + stores[stores.length - 1].id }).then((results) => {
    let docs = [];
    for (let row of results.rows) {
      let doc = row.doc;
      let id = parseFloat(doc._id.split('store_')[1]);
      if (isNaN(id)) {
        throw "Cannot be NaN";
      }
      // iterate through stores from api
      for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        let store = stores[i];
        // find store and local record
        if (store.id === id) {
          let map = PouchProxy.storeToDocMap(store);
          // set revision
          map._rev = doc._rev;
          docs.push(map);
          stores.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    // go through remaining stores and push to docs set
    for (let store of stores) {
      docs.push(PouchProxy.storeToDocMap(store));
    }

    db.bulkDocs(docs).then(() => {
      index++;
      if (index < slices.length) {
        this.commitBatch(db, slices, index, callback);
      }
      else {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using the SQLite Plugin or pure WebSQL? What device/OS are you measuring the performance on? Regular WebView or Crosswalk View?

Comment: Devices we're split, definitely a mistake on my part. Testing both on iPhone  6: The above example was closer to 6-7 seconds, and websql was about 11. The other device is a nexus 4, for that to run the WebSQL example was  13 seconds, so 2 seconds longer. And much much longer 25-30 seconds for the pouchdb. I am using regular websql, not the sqlite plugin.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the issue here is that you are reading all documents into memory in one go (or at least, every document prefixed with `store_`, which is what your `allDocs()` is doing), and then you are writing all of those documents in one go as well.

5000 documents is a lot. And my experience with PouchDB is that there is a sweet spot for `bulkDocs()` (depending on your document size), and it is probably way less than 5000. This applies to both IndexedDB and WebSQL.

Most likely you could speed up your code by batching in chunks of 100-500, while paginating in `allDocs()` using `limit` and `startkey` (i.e. using the strategies described in [this blog post](http://pouchdb.com/2014/04/14/pagination-strategies-with-pouchdb.html)), and then inserting 100-500 at a time using `bulkDocs()`.

As proof that I'm not fibbing, you can check out http://npm-browser.com/, which inserts about 500 metadata documents from npm per batch in a single `bulkDocs()`, and definitely doesn't take 7 seconds per batch. (Most of the time spent is waiting on the network to download the documents.)

Comment: I'll give that a try, and report back. I wouldn't be surprised if i'm doing some nasty things with the pouch db code, it's why i asked :D

Comment: Ran through the blog post, and reduced to pulling values between a start & end key of slices to look up. It's actually quite a bit slower now... At first, i forgot to update the allDocs query, so it ran around the same time. When i noticed that and changed to use the slice start & end ids, it slowed down then.

Comment: Hm, have you tried profiling to see what the issue is? If you see big gaps in the timeline, i.e. where JavaScript is waiting on IndexedDB/WebSQL, then that could give you hints about what's taking so long. Otherwise, it may be worth re-evaluating PouchDB for your user case. If you're not using synchronization, then all the overhead of versioning documents (which is what happens when you update 5,000 documents - you create 5,000 new revisions), may not be worth the tradeoff for you. Something like LocalForage may be more appropriate. You could also try auto_compaction to see if that helps.

Comment: Another helpful thing would be to make a live demo and file an issue on PouchDB. Then we can use it to measure our performance and try to improve. :)

Comment: We're actually hoping to move towards sync with it at somepoint. But our current central storage is a postgres db with a rest api. We're looking at potentially moving parts of that to a couch store instead. I'm just evaluating the mobile pieces, see how that fits together. I'll try profiling it a bit. I just feel like 5,000 records is a small sum of data, was surprised to run into the issue.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce your results: http://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/raw/84028dcfcdc7a0e340b7/. Yes, it is slow to insert/update 5,000 docs. The fastest combo in Chrome seems to be WebSQL without auto-compaction, but it's still around 15 seconds to update 5,000 docs. I've filed an issue: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3921. In the meantime, maybe try having fewer documents? In CouchDB land, your document size should be decided based on the atomic units of "updates" you want to expose to your users. E.g. in the case of a collaborative wiki, each wiki page might be a docoument.

Comment: Interesting finds, thanks. Wasn't able to find time last night to profile, also you seem to be better at it than me :). I think what I'll do is revert to my original code. Yeah it was kinda ugly, but it at least it was 30ish seconds, not 60. I'm wondering though if it's practical to manage a single document for all the stores. Have a doc that contains an array of store objects. My concern though is what this does for lookups & syncing of information.

Comment: [CouchDB best practices](http://docs.ehealthafrica.org/couchdb-best-practices/) might be a good read here. It really depends on your data structure, but the appropriate tradeoffs can be made. Basically, if you don't need to version your "documents" independently, then you can bundle them in an array into fewer Pouch documents. Also, when you are constantly reading your entire database in and out of memory, things generally start to get slow. If you can avoid that somehow, that would be helpful. We will try to improve performance, but even after that, you can expect 2x or 3x, not 10x. :)

Comment: Oh i know, if we planned to use pouch this way, it would be ideal to "fetch locations updated/create since timestamp", and that would help tremendously. We are going to move towards a couch store as I said, so this is more or less a problem in nothing but an experiment :)